# What happens if you use auto-fire during Ocelot's interrogation?

Tags: metal-gear-solid

Before he begins Solid Snake's interrogation, Ocelot says:

[image]

[*"Don't even think about using auto-fire, or I'll know."*](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hZz51KC0O10)

**If you use auto-fire anyway, what happens?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the game detects that you are using autofire, the electrocution continues, controller input is disabled and you'll die.

The game detects autofire via a button-press threshold. If you get over this, the game assumes you use autofire and you'll die.

Reading over some sources, it appears that some auto-fire controllers simply won't work (the auto fire is disabled) and some controllers won't be detected (because they don't reach the button-press threshold).

Sources:

[Metal Gear wikia](http://metalgear.wikia.com/wiki/Revolver_Ocelot)

[liquidsnakesmgs.net](http://www.liquidsnakesmgs.net/mgs1secrets.htm)

Comment: Darn, I was hoping there would be a secret cutscene or something.  Thanks!

Comment: @SteveV. - I think Ocelot has some unique lines he says, when he detects auto-fire. Something like "You have a death-wish, boy?". Could be that this is only in the remake (Twin Snakes), though.

Answer (score -1):

If you USE autofire, you get a Game Over.